# Swift: UICollectionView selecting cell indexPath issues

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to do a `Collection View` whereby someone selects a `cell` and for each selection it takes them to another `View Controller` that holds content of the selection. However I'm running into difficulties as once I apply this line of code to `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`;

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifer("showDetail", sender: self)
```

and then run it in the Simulator the `cell` selection is working according the `indexPath` but its remembering the selections each time I select new `cell`. So for example each `cell` has a photo and label and if I select the first `cell` in the `indexPath` the `segue` takes me first to blank view and then to my selected `cell`. If I select another `cell`, number 3 on the `indexPath` the blank view is now the first `cell` from my previous choice after which it takes to my selected third `cell` . Its doing that every time. If I remove the `performSegueWithIdentifer` code (from Xcode 6.2 (in 6.1.1 it was random)) the selection is my previous choice and never my 'selectedCell', but then at least its only selecting once instead of twice to get to a `view`. There is something going wrong on the `indexPath`. This is the code for my `prepareForSegue`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryBoardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      if segue.identifer == "showDetail" {
          let detailVC:DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
             detailVC.selectedImageName = selectedImage
             detailVC.selectedLabel = selectedLabels
             }
      }
```

I'm stuck on what to do & what solution to apply. Do I keep `performSegueWithIdentifer` code & create an `Equatable` to implement `find(array, selection)` on the `indexPath`? Or could I write a loop, (which seems much easier), that would run through the `indexPath` based upon the selections and that would remove the cell that is no longer selected. However I'm not sure what condition to write in the loop because I don't know the value of the property of the 'selectedCell' because its optional.

```
for (index, value) in enumerate(cellItems) {
//something here to remove 'selectedItem' in the indexPath
}
```

If I remove `performSegueWithIdentifer` code from `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` what can I do in my `prepareForSegue` to get the selection on the correct indexPath?

EDIT the complete code at `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     selectedImage = cellImages[indexPath.row] as String
     selectedLabels = cellLabels[indexPath.row] as String
     self.performSegueWithIdentifer("showDetail", sender: self)
   }
```

I've tried changing sender in the `performSegueWithIdentifer` to `indexPath` but the problem still remains.

EDIT 2 Complete code to my CollectionViewController

```
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var selectedImage = String()
var selectedLabels = String()

var cellImages:[String] = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg", "8.jpg", "9.jpg", "10.jpg", "11.jpg", "13.jpg", "14jpg"]

var cellLabels:[String] = ["Photo 1", "Photo 2", "Photo 3", "Photo 4", "Photo 5", "Photo 6", "Photo 7", "Photo 8", "Photo 9", "Photo 10", "Photo 11", "Photo 12", "Photo 13", "Photo 14"]

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfNumberItemsInSection: Int) -> Int {
    return cellImages.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: PhotoViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReuseableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PhotoViewCell 
    cell.labelCell.text = cellLabels[indexPath.row]
    cell.ImageCell.image = UIImage(named: cellImages[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     selectedImage = cellImages[indexPath.row] as String
     selectedLabels = cellLabels[indexPath.row] as String
     self.performSegueWithIdentifer("showDetail", sender: self)
   }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryBoardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      if segue.identifer == "showDetail" {
          let detailVC:DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
          detailVC.selectedImageName = selectedImage
          detailVC.selectedLabel = selectedLabels
          }
      }
}
```

PhotoViewCell

```
class PhotoViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet var labelCell: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var ImageCell: UIImage!

}
```

EDIT 3 - Amended

I tried your suggestion and unfortunately the problem is still persisting on double views - it's still passing two views before it takes me to the actual selected `cell`. I also amended the code slightly in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` but it still didn't fix the problem.

```
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? PhotoViewCell {

performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetail", sender: cell) 
}
```

However following your other suggestion, in my `StoryBoard` I have added a `segue` from my `Collection View` `cell` to my `DetailViewController`, which has the identifier "showDetail". If I remove `segue` nothing can be selected from my `cells`.

Although it seems the `performSegueWithIdentifer` code is the trigger for the double views because when I remove it, the `cell` is only being selected once, the problem was that the `indexPath` of the `cell` selection was not correct, because it's first selecting on a blank view (is that to do with the showDetail `segue`?), which then puts my `indexPath` out of sync.

EDIT - Solved

This stopped the double selections (the `performSegueWithIdentifier` line was removed): -

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
cellLabels[indexPath.row] as String
cellImages[indexPath.row] as String
   }
}
```

Many Thanks for your help !!!!

Comment: where you set selectedImage and selectedLabel ? You can send the indexPath on the sender self.performSegueWithIdentifer("showDetail", sender: indexPath) or and then in prepareforsegue grab the element of the array with this indexpath.

Comment: @user588125 the selectedImage and selected Label is set in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath.  I tried this self.performSegueWithIdentifer("showDetail", sender: indexPath) but it didn't work. How do I write that into a condition in the prepareForSegue?

Comment: let element = yourArray[indexPath.row]; detailVC.selectedImage = element.selectedImage... can't do more without the actual code.

Comment: Show the code in `func collectionView(,didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)`.

Comment: @user588125 I have tried but indexPath in the prepareForSegue is not recognised I'm struggling to implement it properly

Comment: seems correct to me, upload the project somewhere and i'll check that

Comment: @user588125 edited my question to include all my code to my CollectionViewController & PhotoViewCell

Comment: @JefferyThomas I amended my question after trying your answer unfortunately the problem is still persisting.

Comment: @j03T I didn't use `selectedImage` or `selectedLabels` in my answer. I get the needed values from `cellImages` and `cellLabels` using the `indexPath`. If you need to set `selectedImage` or `selectedLabels` or other reasons, do it in `func prepareForSegue(,sender:)`.

Comment: @JefferyThomas When I select a cell its double selecting two views instead of the one. So now when I select my first cell its firing twice.

Comment: @j03T Do you have `collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`?

Comment: @JefferyThomas Yes - and still doesn't work. I'm starting to think there is bug somewhere I've even tried `collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)` and it doesn't work.

Comment: @JefferyThomas btw thanks for your help its really appreciated. I've been stuck on this for couple of months now. Do you think a loop could fix it?

Comment: @JefferyThomas Its fixed!!!!! I removed the `performSegueWithIdentifer` code and replaced it with `cellLabels[indexPath.row] as String` / `cellImages[indexPath.row] as String` in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(NOTE: I updated this for Swift 4 and more modern practices.)

I stick to `UIView` objects as much as possible.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else { return }

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: cell)
}
```

Then in `prepare(for:sender:)`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "showDetail":
        guard let indexPath = (sender as? UIView)?.findCollectionViewIndexPath() else { return }
        guard let detailViewController = segue.destination as? DetailViewController else { return }

        detailViewController.selectedImageName = cellImages[indexPath.row]
        detailViewController.selectedLabel = cellLabels[indexPath.row]

    default: return
    }
}
```

---

I used an extension I created a while ago `findCollectionViewIndexPath()`

```
extension UIView {

    func findCollectionView() -> UICollectionView? {
        if let collectionView = self as? UICollectionView {
            return collectionView
        } else {
            return superview?.findCollectionView()
        }
    }

    func findCollectionViewCell() -> UICollectionViewCell? {
        if let cell = self as? UICollectionViewCell {
            return cell
        } else {
            return superview?.findCollectionViewCell()
        }
    }

    func findCollectionViewIndexPath() -> IndexPath? {
        guard let cell = findCollectionViewCell(), let collectionView = cell.findCollectionView() else { return nil }

        return collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
    }

}
```

---

I have a suspicion that you have a segue in the storyboard already and don't need `func collectionView(, didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)`, but either way, the prepare segue should work.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let iPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems
    let indexPath : NSIndexPath = iPath![0] as NSIndexPath
    let rowIndex = indexPath.row
    print("row index = \(rowIndex)")
}
```